# Basic Jmeter Load Test: 10k different user concurrent login. All 10k user should registered first in system?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I want to test 10000 different user login to the web based application. I have read about CSV Data Config but I want to ask basic question first. Should I register that 10k user in system or jmeter can simulate it without real/dummy user id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of JMeter's [core use cases](https://jmeter.apache.org/) include GETting and POSTing data, not clicking through HTML pages like Selenium. Given that fact, if you really want to test the logins of 10k different users, I would say that running logins through JMeter depends on one question: Is there a simple POST request you can make to register a new account?

If so, then we can leverage that in the performance test to first send the POST request to register the new account, and then GETting the login form and POSTing those login credentials. There is a [cool video tutorial on login using JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421705-How-to-use-JMeter-for-Login-Authentication) created by the Blazemeter folks. If, however, you can't register a new account with a simple POST request, then I would say that it's likely that you will need to pre-register them first - maybe using Selenium.

I hope that helps.